# How to have a good output in bash when printing?

Tags: regex

I have this command here, and I have a problem achieving a good format.

In this lines,

```
DATE*2014*09*23
VAL*0001*ABC
N3*Sample
VAL*0002*XYZ
```

My desired output here is like this:

```
["ABC", "XYC"]
```

I tried this code:

```
perl -nle 'print $& if /VAL\*[0-9]*\*\K.*/' file | awk '{ printf "\"%s\",", $0 }'
```

resulting only:

```
"ABC","XYZ",
```

Another thing is that when printing only one value.

If it happens that a file is like this:

```
DATE*2014*09*23
VAL*0001*ABC
N3*Sample
```

my desired output would only be like this (ignoring the output of having []):

```
 "ABC"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all with awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS="*"; i=0; ORS=""}
$1=="VAL" {a[i++]=$3}

END { 
    if (i>1) {
        print "[\"" a[0]
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
            print  "\",\"" a[j]
        print "\"]"
    }
    if (i==1)
        print "\"" a[0] "\""
}
```